# how to use seaborn to draw a barplot with different colors on different groubed variables

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I'm trying to draw a barplot with different colors on different grouped variables.
I'm using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

index_list = ["factor_" + str(x+1) for x in range(5)]
data = pd.DataFrame(index = index_list)
for i in range(5):
    data["stock_" + str(i+1)] = np.random.randint(1,10,5)

sns.barplot(data = data, x = data["stock_1"], y = data.index)
```

what I got are 5 bars with different colors. If I want the first two bars have the same color(assume they belong to the same group), the second two bars have the same color, and put a legend on the right side, how to do that?
Help me plz:)
[barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGnl2.png)

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

index_list = ["factor_" + str(x+1) for x in range(5)]
data = pd.DataFrame(index = index_list)
for i in range(5):
    data["stock_" + str(i+1)] = np.random.randint(1,10,5)

clrs = palette=["b" if 1<=x+1<=2 else ('r' if 3<=x+1<=4 else 'k')for x in range(5)]
sns.barplot(data = data, x = data["stock_1"], y = data.index, palette=clrs)
```

Output:
[image]